# Program seems to freeze after executing a function?

Tags: c

I am doing a program that is a customer order application. Basically it is a database (like e-bay) where a customer must be registered in the system to buy a product. The problem I am currently having is when I come to modify a customer.

Basically when I run the program I have a menu. I choose customer and I have a sub-menu and I choose to modify the customer data. then it asks me for an id and the program checks whether it is valid or not. If the id number is valid it goes on to let you choose which criteria you want to modify. After the modification of that criteria it prints out ~~~ITEM EDITED~~~ and then it just like freeze. Nothing comes afterwards and I have to terminate the program myself.

This happens as well when an invalid id is entered. When this happens it prints out the main menu and when I enter a number to choose from the main menu nothing happens.

I tried solving it myself but cannot find the problem. I tried to use `exit(0)` instead of `break;` after the cases but same problem happened. Here under is the code of the modify function. Just to let you know that I have a header file with all the necessary information such as structure declaration.

```
modify_customer()
{
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

char another;
int flag = 0;
int choice;
char x[8];

FILE *pCust;
int size;

printf("\nENTER CUSTOMER ID NUMBER: ");
//fflush(stdout);
scanf("%s",x);

flag = checkcustomer(x);

if(flag==0)
{
    pCust=fopen("customer.txt","r+b");
    rewind(pCust);

    while(fread(&cust,sizeof(cust),1,pCust))
    {
        if(strcmp(cust.id,x)==0)
        {
            printf("\nid ==> %s",cust.id);
            printf("\nname ==> %s",cust.name);
            printf("\nsurname ==> %s",cust.surname);
            printf("\naddress ==> %s",cust.address);
            printf("\nDO YOU WANT TO EDIT THIS REDORD [Y/N]: ");
            scanf("%s", &another);
            fflush(pCust);

            if(another=='Y'|| another=='y')
            {
                printf("\n(1) EDIT ID NUMBER");
                printf("\n(2) EDIT NAME");
                printf("\n(3) EDIT SURNAME");
                printf("\n(4) EDIT ADDRESS");

                printf("\nenter choice (1) - (4) to edit: ");
                //fflush(stdout);
                scanf("%d",&choice);

                switch(choice)
                {
                case 1 : printf("\nEDIT RECORD [ID]");
                         printf("\nenter new customerID:");
                         scanf("%s",cust.id);
                         size = sizeof(cust);
                         fseek(pCust,-size,SEEK_CUR);
                        fwrite(&cust,sizeof(cust),1,pCust);
                         break;

                case 2 : printf("\nEDIT RECORD [NAME]");
                         printf("\nenter new name: ");
                         //fflush(stdout);
                         scanf("%s",cust.name);
                         size = sizeof(cust);
                         fseek(pCust,-size,SEEK_CUR);
                        fwrite(&cust,sizeof(cust),1,pCust);
                         break;

                case 3 : printf("\nEDIT RECORD [SURNAME]");
                         printf("\nenter new surname: ");
                         //fflush(stdout);
                         scanf("%s",cust.surname);
                         size = sizeof(cust);
                         fseek(pCust,-size,SEEK_CUR);
                        fwrite(&cust,sizeof(cust),1,pCust);
                         break;

                case 4 : printf("\nEDIT RECORD [ADDRESS]");
                         printf("\nenter new address: ");
                         //fflush(stdout);
                         scanf("%s",cust.address);
                         size = sizeof(cust);
                         fseek(pCust,-size,SEEK_CUR);
                        fwrite(&cust,sizeof(cust),1,pCust);
                         break;
                }
                printf("\n~~~ITEM EDITED~~~");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nRECORDS ARE NOT MODIFIED");
                customer_menu();
            }
        }
    }
}
if(flag==1)
{
    printf("\nITEM DOES NOT EXIST. TRY AGAIN");
    main_menu();
}
fflush(stdout);
getch();
fclose(pCust);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your scanf("%d") and similar makes no error checking - if someone enters something non-numeric, the program will hang!

Comment: `while(fread(&cust,sizeof(cust),1,pCust))` - what happens if this returns EOF?

Comment: The getch() at the end of the function seems suspect... Does pressing Enter once more have any effect?

Comment: matt petersson all info is stored in strings as for example the id might have letters

Comment: chris no nothing happens.  i tried every character by the program in like in an infinite loop (printing nothing) and every input you enter does nothing. you have to terminate the program to exit

Comment: mats petersson- it never returned EOF. This is a school project and we didn't went into a lot of detail in c as only 3 months we had available.

Comment: You might go learning how to use a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: I had begun a fairly sizable answer to this question, when I noticed a pattern in the points I was making: **you need to show more code**. You call functions without showing us definitions, use what I can only guess is a Customer type without showing us it's definition, and use a `cust` variable without declaring it. Since the cust variable is used in the evaluation of the while expression, this might be causing the infinite loop.

Comment: the cust is there for the following code
typedef struct customer
    {
 char id[ID_NUMBER];
 char name[20];
 char surname[20];
 char address[50];
    }customer;

    customer cust;

Comment: the cust is there for the following code

    typedef struct customer
    {
 char id[ID_NUMBER];
 char name[20];
 char surname[20];
 char address[50];
    }customer;

    customer cust;

it is there to call the structure. the structure is in a header file. in the header file there is also the decleration of the method. so from that end i am covered.

checkcustomer(x) is there to check if the id number matches a customer id that is in the database already. if it is it returns (flag = 0), else returns (flag !=0). which value of flag returns the program executes accordingly.

Comment: sorry if it is messy but i am new to posting and i am not sure if i am doing it right.